# how to get recently viewed application lists in android

Tags: android

I'm developing application in android which need the recently viewed application with time.I have tried using activity manager.but it is not working perfectly.Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

`getRecentTasks()`

Return a list of the tasks that the user has recently launched, with the most recent being first and older ones after in order.
It returns a list of recently run apps. Simply take the list and add your own UI to it.

## Note:

For Lolipop

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { 
    UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager)getSystemService("usagestats");                       
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    List<UsageStats> stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000*10, time);                                    
}
```

[refer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks%28int,%20int%29) & [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getAppTasks())

Comment: Thank you.Actually it just returning the application whatever running in the background too.I need the list like only if the application is launched.

Comment: Lollipop deprecated the method; however there is a new API that allows you to view app usage. `UsageStatsManager` can be used in that case.